# Updating a TextBox based on a ListBox selection (XAML)

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a listbox that is displaying several attributes from an XML file. How can I update a textbox whenever you select one of these items on the listbox? My listbox looks like this:

```
<ListBox Name="RouterSelection" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RoutingData}, XPath=Routes/Route/IdClient}"/>
```

and my textbox looks like this:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding ElementName=RouterSelection, Path=SelectedItem}" Text="{Binding XPath=@Value}"/>
```

But the textbox is not showing the content when you select any of the items. What am I missing? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=RouterSelection, Path=SelectedValue}"/>
```

and set SelectedValuePath for ListBox